# Passing particle position(glm vec3s) vertices to vertex buffer objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, particle-system

I have particle and particle system class. In my main program, I created an instance of particle system and initialized the particles in it. In the display function, I would like to pass the position of all particles to the Vertex buffer in one shot. But I'm not sure of the notation used to access all position vertices from the.

```
class particle{
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec3 vel;
}


class particleSystem{
    std::vector<particle> m_particles; 
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
//Displaying particles starts here
glGenBuffers(1, &particleBuffers); 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, particleBuffers);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ps.m_particles[].pos), ps.m_particles[].pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(position_loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (GLsizei)ps.m_particles.size());         //Draw them to screen
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
//Displaying particles ends here
```

where `ps` is an instance of the particlesystem class. The notation I used to access all positions of the particles in the glBufferData function does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider uploading the ***entire*** particle vector to the GPU like this:

```
struct particle {
  glm::vec3 pos;
  glm::vec3 vel;
};

[...]

glBufferData          (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (particle) * ps.m_particles.size (), 
                       &ps.m_particles [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer (position_loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof (particle), 0);
```

<sup>I am not sure how your original code actually worked, these fields have private access by default if you declare `particle` as a class.</sup>

#### There are two points to mention here:

1. `&ps.m_particles [0]` is the standard method to acquire a pointer to a contiguous block of memory representing your vector's data store.
2. Since your particle data structure contains two fields, your stride is non-zero.

   - This is the second-to-last parameter in the call to `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`.

---

#### Alternatively, you might consider a separate data structure to store the data you actually need for rendering from the data you need for CPU-side simulation:

```
struct particle_vtx {
  glm::vec3 pos;
  //glm::vec3 color;
};

struct particle_state {
  glm::vec3 vel;
  //GLuint texture;
};

[...]

class particleSystem {
  std::vector<particle_vtx>   m_particle_verts;
  std::vector<particle_state> m_particle_states;
};
```

This is probably the more versatile solution in the end, because you will have two pools of contiguous memory that separate what the GPU needs from what the CPU needs. You will be much more memory efficient (on the GPU side) and will not require any special processing when it comes time to send the vertex data to the GPU. Granted stateful particle systems can be implemented completely on the GPU these days, start small.

Comment: Well I had that thought in mind to create the data structure separately for the particle's attribute for easy accessibility. But then I thought that having a particle class would be more appropriate in terms managing code. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an integer value into the vector array operator.  If you are trying to create an array of `glm::vec3` to pass into `glBufferData`, you'll have to do so manually - probably through use of a for loop and dynamic allocation.